# Issue using foundation javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I've been doing a project using the foundation-rails gem and now that I've got to a part where I need to use its javascript - a reveal modal, it doesn't seem to be working, I can't get any of the foundation javascript features to work and have tried for hours to no avail.

app/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation.min
//= require modernizr.custom.72741
//= require fastclick
//= require foundation.reveal
//= require_tree .



$(document).foundation();
```

relevant parts of application.html.haml

```
%head
    %meta{charset:"utf-8"}
    %meta{name:"viewport", content:"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}
    %title Instaharam
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr"
    = csrf_meta_tags
    %link{href:"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script", rel:"stylesheet", type:"text/css"}
%body
    ...
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

mark-up to display the modal

```
%li= link_to "Add a post", '#', :'data-reveal-id' => 'add-post-modal'

#add-post-modal.reveal-modal
                - @new_post = Post.new
                = form_for @new_post, data: {abide: true}, :html => {:multipart => true } do |f|
                    = f.label :image
                    = f.file_field :image, required: true
                    = f.label :caption
                    = f.text_field :caption
                    = f.submit name: "Create Post"
                %a.close-reveal-modal& &#215;
```

When I click the link it simply takes me to the top of the page.

Comment: Are you getting any useful errors in the inspector?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors at all in the inspector.

Comment: Can you share some of the markup you're using to trigger the modal?

Comment: @cdmwebs I just added it to the question.

Comment: you sure it works properly with turbolinks?

Comment: Hmm. The only thing I see that's missing is the `data-reveal` tag on the `#add-post-modal`.